# Google Glass interaction sounds

Tags: android, audio, google-glass

Is there any way I can get the Google Glass interaction sounds? For example, the tapping sounds or swiping-through list sounds, etc? I have implemented a horizontal listview, but when you are swiping through it there isn't the default swiping-though sound. Is that a bug or its intent to be like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are implementing your own widgets instead of the built-in ones, you will need to play the sounds yourself at the appropriate times.

The [`Sounds`](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/media/Sounds) class in the GDK defines constants that you can pass to the [`AudioManager.playSoundEffect`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#playSoundEffect%28int%29) method in order to play these sounds.

Comment: OH! TONY YOU ARE THE BEST =p

Answer (score 0):

I pulled the glass sound apk and unzipped it and then rezipped the sound files. You can access them at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_wqfoqX2ZxGRnJzN2dPZlZZZVk/edit?usp=sharing and then select Download from the File menu.﻿

This may help you add sounds in your app, technically.

Disclamier: I'm not sure if it's OK legally to add the sounds to your app.